# Translation from English

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I would really appreciate if someone could translate this into German:

> It (it's about a country) should be in zone 1, because it is in EU.

Comment: It is not a translation web site. Try to use google translator or any other online/offline translation service.

Comment: Wrong forum. We do not provide a translation service. All questions **must** address **a specific issue** concerning the German language. Say, you'd tried to translate the sentence yourself and you had faced a particular problem, you could ask here by describing what was causing you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if this is not a translate website (please keep in mind for next time).

Es sollte sich in der ersten Zone befinden, da es zur EU gehört.

Comment: Thank you very much and I apologize for my ignorance.(I know it's not a good excuse,but i was in a hurry)